# Deriving a formula satisfying the given criteria.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm sorry for the vague title but Math isn't my strongest subject and I'm not sure how to describe this in mathematical terminology.

I'm trying to figure out a formula where I can find a numbers value relative to another scale. In my instance I have an attack radius of 9 which can be reduced down to 1.5. Thus my scale 9 to 1.5. If I pass the 9 into my formula I want to get back the number 4, and if I pass in the number 1.5 I want to get back 0. So, I have another scale 4 to 1.5.

My question is what number do I get back if I pass in 4? or 5? or raise or lower one of the scales as they are all variable figures? There must be a standard formula with variables I can use to calculate this without too much trouble but I can't seem to figure it out. Please try to keep answers as simple as the math will allow. Thank you for looking and I hope I explained my problem well enough.

Comment: If you pass 9 into your formula, why would you get 4? Is this another example and not connected to the previous one or I am not able to understand?

Comment: 4 is the answer to the formula I want if I were to plug in the number 9. So 9x = 4 AND 1.5x = 0. That doesn't work but some kind of formula must be able to help. Does that help explain?

Comment: I think you mean $f(9)=4$ and $f(1.5)=0$ where $f(x)=y$ is a formula in which input is $x$ and output is $y$. Right?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, infinitely many formulas can be made that satisfy your criteria, but I am mentioning probably simplest one.

$$y=\frac{8x-12}{15}$$

Here $x$ is input and $y$ is output.

This is actually a line in passing through the points $(9,4)$ and $(1.5,0)$ in the $xy$ plane.

You can derive the equation in general for a line passing through points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$  using the following equation :

$$y-y_1=\left(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\right) (x-x_1)$$

Comment: @BrianLegg does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, very simple. It's great. I'll mark as answer but would you mind telling me how you got to the solution? I ask because these are all variables meaning the 9 may be a 10 later and should return 4.5 or something. I don't want to return just because I change a parameter.

Comment: @BrianLegg I just wrote equation of a straight line passing through points $(9,4)$ and $ (1.5,0)$ Do you know how to do that? Tell me and I'll add that in my answer, in general for any points.